# Integrating Firebase with Xamarin.Android

Tags: firebase, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-component

Reviewing the Xamarin components, it appears there is no explicit component for integrating `Firebase Database` with Xamarin.Android, but there is one for `Firebase Storage` and a component for Xamarin.iOS `Firebase Database`.

Given there is no explicit component for Xamarin.Android`Firebase Database`, can I use the logic to connect to firebase using the `Firebase Storage` component, then query the database using the same methods found in Xamarin.iOS `Firebase Database` doc?

Xamarin.Android `Firebase Storage`: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebase-storage
Xamarin.iOS `Firebase Database`: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseiosdatabase

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post actually it works perfectly fine using Firebase.Xamarin